# How to automatically create rows in table after updating another table

Tags: sql

I am developing a Web Application. In database of web application, I have a table named Daily in which I am making entries on Daily basis. let us say it has 3 columns A, B and C. I have another table named Monthly in which I store same A, B, C values on monthly basis. Now what I want is that when one month completes i.e no of entries in daily table becomes 30 or 31 then a new row gets created automatically in monthly table whose A, B, and C values will contain the sum of all values in Daily table of corresponding A, B, C values.
I want to know how I can do this using SQL and if not what is other way to do this ?

Comment: You would schedule a job on the first day of each month to summarize the daily values.  The details depend on the database and system you are using.

Comment: As @GordonLinoff says, job schedules depend on the database you are working in. Can you tell us what kind of database you're using?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Gordon Linoff's response is probably a good way to go, depending on your database, OS, programming language etc.

Another way is to create a "trigger" on the Daily table, which automatically performs the summarization when the row for the last day of the month is inserted.  Please note: Triggers are tricky, and can complicate maintenance and replication.

I'll make it a little more concrete, to make the explanation easier.  Also, the details of syntax will depend on your specific choice of database.  This answer will use PostgreSQL syntax.

Here's the Daily table.  I have added a column to contain the date, and made it the primary key.

```
CREATE TABLE daily
(
  daily_date date NOT NULL,
  a integer NOT NULL,
  b integer NOT NULL,
  c integer NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT daily_pkey PRIMARY KEY (daily_date)
);
```

And here is the Monthly table:

```
CREATE TABLE monthly
(
  monthly_date date NOT NULL,
  a_sum integer NOT NULL,
  b_sum integer NOT NULL,
  c_sum integer NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT monthly_pkey PRIMARY KEY (monthly_date)
);
```

Now we create a procedure to be called when the last daily row of the month is inserted.  In PostgreSQL, this is a special type called a trigger function.  The details vary wildly depending on your database.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION summarize_month()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$DECLARE 
    month_begin DATE :=
        make_date(
            cast (extract(year from new.daily_date) as integer),
            cast (extract(month from new.daily_date) as integer),
            1);
    month_end DATE :=   
        month_begin + interval '1 month' - interval '1 day';
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO monthly(monthly_date, a_sum, b_sum, c_sum)
    (SELECT month_begin, sum(a), sum(b),sum(c)
    FROM daily
    WHERE daily_date BETWEEN month_begin AND month_end);
    return null;

END;$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

This procedure figures out the beginning and ending date of the month to be summarized, based on the `daily_date` of the row that was just inserted.  It then inserts a new row into the `monthly` table, containing the summarized data computed by the `SELECT` statement.

Finally, we attach the trigger function to the `daily` table, and tell it to execute only when the row for the last day of the month is inserted.

```
CREATE TRIGGER summarize_daily_to_monthly
  AFTER INSERT
  ON daily
  FOR EACH ROW
  WHEN ((date_part('month'::text, new.daily_date) <> 
         date_part('month'::text, (new.daily_date + 1))))
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE summarize_month();
```

I know this is a long answer to what sounds like a simple problem.  Please feel free to ask if you need further clarification.